# Compare string for italic and bold character

Tags: java, eclipse

I am comparing two string using the **equals()** method:

```
   if(String1.equals(String2))
   {
     String match="Text Match"
   }
```

With this way the equals method compares strings which include spaces.

But here **String1** and **String2** contain italic and bold character.

So what should i use so that it also compares for italic and bold characters.

Answer (score 3):

Strings contain only characters, italic and bold are mere interpretations of characters by a GUI and should therefore not collide with any string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The class `String` in Java does not contain information if the text value is italic or bold or normal. They represent just the value, the sequence of characters. You probably should look at `Font`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html